# How to run filtering tests in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have to run tests in a specific order using `build.gradle` file.
I have the `build.gradle` file looks like the following:

```
test {
    include 'com.my-project.MyTestClass'
    include 'com.my-project.MyTestClass1'
}
```

but when I running test task I have the following message:

```
Tests event were not received
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is it your complete **build.gradle** ?

Comment: @M3hdi no. It is just a part of build.gradle which connected with tests.

Comment: do you use Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message just means that no tests were actually run. There could be a number of reasons for that, but the most likely given your example is that the [include](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:include(java.lang.String[])) method takes an Ant style file pattern, but you have given it (fully qualified) class names. Also, 'my-project' is not a valid package name, but I assume this is just a error in your example here.

But more importantly, if your intent is to run tests in a specific order, you will not achieve that with a single test task. The specified `includes` just tell Gradle what tests are part of the suite, but doesn't affect the order.

I don't know what test framework you are using, but I also don't think it is possible with JUnit 4 and 5. The only way I can think of is to create multiple Test tasks in Gradle, where each task represent a single unit test (or group of tests that can be run in any order), and where you order each task through `dependsOn`. So something like this:

```
task myTest1(type: Test) {
    include 'example/MyTestClass1.class'
}

task myTest2(type: Test) {
    dependsOn myTest1
    include 'example/MyTestClass2.class'
}

test {
    exclude 'example/**'
    dependsOn myTest2
}
```